# Autoload custom library in Zend Framework 2.0

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, zend-framework2

I need to use autoloading for my custom classes in Zend Framework **2.0**. My custom library located in `/vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey`. I have a simple extended AbstractTable class in `/vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey/Db/Table/AbstractTable.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Garvey\Db\Table;

use Zend\Db\Table\AbstractTable;

abstract class AbstractTable extends AbstractTable
{
    public function getItemById($id)
    {

    }
}
```

In the index.php I have the following code:

```
require_once 'vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
    'prefixes' => array(
        'Garvey' => 'vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey',
    )
)));
```

But I have the following error. What I have missed?

```
Fatal error: Class 'Garvey\Db\Table\AbstractTable' not found
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what? that's wrong look at the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

Comment: It is a Zend Framework 2. Beta1.

Comment: Why do you use an older version... (2min)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your original index.php would also worked if you changed the 'prefixes' key to 'namespaces' and specify path like below:

```
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'Garvey' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/Garvey',
    )
)));
```

Comment: Nice answer, just a little correction for this specific question: `'Garvey' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey'`

Comment: plutov, you shouldn't need: require_once 'vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

Answer (score 11):

Or you can defime method in Module.php

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    $return = array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
        ), 
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'Garvey' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey',
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But I would not recommend it. Since ZF2 purpose all centered about speed in autoloading the best way is to use class_map style to load your classes. It will work much quicker at the end but require additional work.  You can to register every class in you class_map file.

You can create class_map.php in the root of your library and place there

```
<?php
return array(
    'Garvey\Db\Table\AbstractTable' => __DIR__ . '/Garvey/Db/Table/AbstractTable.php', 
);
```

And add there as many classes as you use. And in getAutoloaderConfig() you can add you classmap

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    $return = array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey/class_map.php',
        ), 
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer. Using a class map is the a fast (if not the fastest) way to load classes and therefor recommended by Zend. It's also clear and easy traceable. Good job clearing this method out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney explains in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZzfhTqorA0&t=14m31s) that there are now 3 methods for autoloading :

- ZF1-style include_path autoloader ( *old zf1 method, not recommended* )
- Per-namespace/prefix autoloading ( *new zf2 method, better* )
- [Class-map autoloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html) ( *recommended and the fastest* )

A [class-map generator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html) utility is mentioned in the docs that will take care of writing the `/vendor/vendor_name/library/autoload_classmap.php` for you.

The solution you found is similar to the one Matthew mentions in the video for the Per-namespace/prefix autoloading. Following the code structure in [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), that code would go in the `/init_autoloader.php` file, rather than in the `/public/index.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. Put this in your index.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Garvey', realpath('vendor/Garvey/library/Garvey'));
$loader->register();
```

Comment: mmm a little frustrating. You may be new but I'm even newer! Where does the above go? I'm thinking public/index.php

Comment: Actually the correct way would be to have a module for this (only adding an autoloader to the application).

Comment: You are not right. Module - is a part of application. Vendor - is a part for different applications.

Answer (score 2):

Have a quick look at [this post](http://kdecom.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/how-to-add-custom-library-in-your-zend.html).

Now next step is add some code into our custom library.

First of all open a file `./vendor/Garvey/autoload_classmap.php`

```
return array(

    'Garvey\Module' => __DIR__ . '/Module.php',

    'Garvey\Db\Table' => __DIR__ . '/library/Garvey/Db/Table/AbstractTable.php',

)
```

Next is `./vendor/Garvey/Module.php`

```
namespace Garvey;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),

            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/library/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Now inside your library create a file inside a folder:

`./vendor/Kdecom/library/Kdecom/Db/Table/AbstractTable.php`

One final thing that we need to do which is add this library into your `application.config.php` file.

So your `application.config.php` file will looks something like this way...

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Garvey'
    ),

    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Post link returns 404