# zendframework 2 - where to save custom library folder

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Zendframework-1, we usually save the customized code under library folder (parallel to application folder) almost using the same folder structure as zend framework (vendor) library to create plugin or extend core library.

In zend framework 2, folder structure is changed. zend vendor core library is moved under Vendor folder and application folder is moved into Module (root) folder.

My question is, which is the best place to save customized plugin/code based library folder in ZF2?

Anyone else have gone through this phase?

Comment: Check this post on stackoverflow...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559107/autoload-custom-library-in-zend-framework-2-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the purpose of your **library**

Case 1, **used by many modules**:
Place it in your vendor folder, make sure to be PSR-0 compliant, that makes autoloading easy.

Case 2, **used by only one module**:
Place it in under `modules/your_module/src` and edit the `Module.php`s `getAutoloaderConfig()` method to have it autoloaded.

```
....

class Module {

....

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',      // classmap for production usage
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__, // your module's files autoloading (development usage and fallback)
                'library_namespace' => __DIR__ . '/src/librarys_namespace/potential_subfolder', // your library files autoloading (development usage and fallback). eg: 'acme' => '/src/acme/library' for acme namespace
            ),
        ),
    );
}

....
```

Case 3, **your library is 3rd party module**:
Place it within the vendor folder, for references look at [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser)

I think your use-case would most like be case 1, your library modifies behaviour of e.g. the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` or additional plugins.
**But** if a plugin is only used by one module you'll be better of placing it parallel to your Modules code as described in Case 2.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll ask the blog owner to link to my original work. (I won't sue him 'cause most of these things are pretty boilerplate, but let's be honest, I put some work in answering the best way I could imagine and dont want to be copied for free)

Answer (score 5):

`./vendor` if your code has generic purposes (i.e.: Classes like StdClass, ArrayAccess, Iterator, etc...). In short, if those Classes are required for Modules to work, they should be inside vendor.

`./module` In case your Plugins/Code are meant for a specific purpose (and Standalone), you may evaluate if it's a module or not (i.e.: ZF-Commons 3rd Party Modules/Plugins like ZfcUser)