# How to include a library to a Zend Framework 2 application using namespace based autoloading?

Tags: namespaces, zend-framework2, autoload, zend-autoloader

I created a subfolder `MyNamespace` in `/vendor/` (is it the correct place for own libraries?) and want to use classes like `MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\MyCustomRouter` in my application. How can I include this library to my namespace based autoloading?

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559107/autoload-custom-library-in-zend-framework-2-0?rq=1

Comment: I've tried so, how [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10974043/2019043) shown (with `Module#getAutoloaderConfig()` and `'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace'`), but my classes cann still not be found.

Comment: Did you create a Module.php file in `/vendor/MyNamespace/` to do that?

Comment: No, I didn't. But it's not a Module, it's a library -- like ZF. The ZF library folder also has no `Module` class in it.

Comment: The ZF library uses the standard autoloader, the accepted answer on the linked page describes adding your own library using zends autoloader by placing the code in index.php (obviously change the namespace and path to match your own lib)

Comment: There's actually a lot of ways to do this. You could just add your namespace and path to `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` (assuming composer is in use). Honestly though, if the lib is going to be used with Zend Mvc, why not make it a module? The skeleton app is set up to look for modules in `vendor` anyway.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good simple possiblity to the library as module, but it is not a module. OK, I've tried `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` out (`'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir . '/MyNamespace',`). The error is still there.

Comment: If I add `'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace',` to the array in `Application\Module#getAutoloaderConfig()` and/or `OtherModule\Module#getAutoloaderConfig()` and call a class from the library (`use MyNamespace\Path\To\MyClass; $test = new MyClass();`) in a view, the server returns an `error 502`.

Comment: sounds like your namespace isn't psr0 compliant, assuming a path of `vendor/MyNamespace/src/MyNamespace` for composers `autoload_namespaces` you would use `'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir . '/MyNamespace/src/'`, and in a modules `getAutoloadConfig()` it would be `'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace/src/MyNamespace'`

Comment: I had defined the incorrect library path: `'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir . '/MyNamespace',` for the folder `/vendor/MyNamespace`. The correct path for this folder would be `'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir,`. Now I've corrected this: `'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir . '/MyNamespace/library',` for `/vendor/MyNamespace/library/MyNamespace` and it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please make an answer from your comment with `autoload_namespaces`. It will be usefull for other and I'll get a possibility to thank you in form of an answer-acceptation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `init_autoloader.php` and change the `if ($zf2Path) {` section to be:

```php
if ($zf2Path) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                    'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/vendor/MyNamespace',
                ),                    
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Note the addition of the `MyNamespace` key within the `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader` section.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rob's answer, some other ways to autoload a custom library

First, make sure your folder structure is psr0 compliant

A typical structure for the mythical psr0 compliant MyNamespace library used in the examples

```
vendor/
    MyNamespace/
        lib/
            MyNamespace/
                FooClass.php
                BarClass.php
```

Include from a Module.php file using `getAutoloaderConfig`

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace/lib/MyNamespace',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Directly in `index.php` using the `AutoloaderFactory` to configure the `StandardAutoloader`

```
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
    'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'namespaces' => array(
            'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/MyNamespace/lib/MyNamespace',
        ),
    )
));
```

You could even do the same in a ./config/autoload/ file

```
<?php    
// file ./config/autoload/namespaces.local.php

Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
     'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
         'namespaces' => array(
             'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace/lib/MyNamespace',
         ),
     )
));
```

A further alternative to include your lib is to edit `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'MyNamespace\\' => $vendorDir . '/MyNamespace/lib/',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the [composer autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"MyNamespace\\": "vendor/MyNamespace/"}
}}
```